# Use output data from Copy activity in subsequent activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a ForEach activity which uses a Copy activity with an HTTP source and a blob storage sink to download a json file for each item. The HTTP source is set to Binary Copy whereas the blob storage sink is not, since I want to both copy the complete json file to blob storage and also extract some data from each json file and store this data in a database table in the following activity.

In the blob storage sink, I've added a column definition which extracts some data from the json file. The json files are stored in blob storage successfully, but how can I access the extracted data in the subsequent stored procedure activity?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using lookup activity to extract the data in the Blob and use the output in later activity. Refer to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity to see whether lookup activity can satisfy your requirements.